# Getting specific element from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

On executing elastic search and storing the result in JSON form

```
stdClass Object (
    [took] => 119
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => stdClass Object (
        [total] => 5 
        [successful] => 5 
        [failed] => 0 
    )
    [hits] => stdClass Object (
        [total] => 3 
        [max_score] => 1 
        [hits] => Array ( 
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [_index] => movies 
                [_type] => movie 
                [_id] => 3 
                [_score] => 1 
                [_source] => stdClass Object (
                    [title] => The MATRIX 
                    [year] => 1975
                )
            )
            [1] => stdClass Object (
                [_index] => movies
                [_type] => movie
                [_id] => 8
                [_score] => 1
                [_source] => stdClass Object (
                    [title] => The MATRIX
                    [year] => 1975
                )
            )
            [2] => stdClass Object (
                [_index] => movies
                [_type] => movie
                [_id] => 4
                [_score] => 1
                [_source] => stdClass Object (
                    [title] => The MATRIX
                    [year] => 1975
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I want to get value of each movie and year in the above
I tried

```
foreach($result as $i)
{
    echo $i->title;
    echo $i->year;
}


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\esearch\index.php on line 16

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\esearch\index.php on line 17
```

How to get it?

Comment: Try to convert your json to associative array with passing true on second parameter `json_decode($yourjson, true)`.

Comment: The problem isn't the getter, it's the fact that `$i` isn't an object (seeing how it's `119`, then empty, and *then* an stdClass.

Comment: @fian - already done that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following;

```
foreach($result->hits->hits as $movie)
{
    echo $movie->_source->title;
    echo $movie->_source->year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    foreach($result->hits->hits as $i)
    {
        echo $i->_source->title;
        echo $i->_source->year;

    }
```